# Calling code as labels or as functions in CIL?

Tags: cil, il

I've spent the past few days of my free time learning CIL and was wondering about branching to a label (br ) vs calling a method (.method declaration).

I know that if you declare a method, you will be able to access that from outside the assembly, but what about making private methods labels and just using `br` to branch to it? Is there any performance gain to be had with that?

To clear up the confusion, here is a simplified example (due to space and time restrictions):

```
// calling code
ldc.i4 5
call int32 testmethod(int32)
// other code

// method
.method public int32 testmethod(int32) 
{
    ldc.i4 10
    add
    ldc.i4 20
    mul
    ret
}
```

So instead of doing that method, I could do that with labels and branches:

```
ldc.i4 5
br testlabel
leftoff:
// remaining instructions

testlabel:
.lcd.i4 10
add
ldc.i4 20
mul
br leftoff
```

So the method/label testlabel takes and int32 and then adds 10 and multiplies that result by 20. Simple enough. I realize that the one thing that a drawback (that I didn't mention originally) is readability, but if this is generated by a compiler readability becomes less important. So by using the second example, would using the labels and branching to the code offer any performance benefits? If not, what about if I would be able to fit it in a short branch? (br.s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is basically method inlining.  Although it is possible that inlining a method will improve performance, there are several reasons that you might choose not to inline a method:

- If the method is used several times, then it will probably need to be inlined several times.  This can result in an overall increase in the size of the generated IL, and can possibly result in worse performance.
- Sometimes, a method can't be inlined.  For instance, a recursive method clearly can't be inlined (since it would need to be inlined again in the inlined body, ad infinitum), nor can a virtual method (assuming that you don't know the runtime type of the callee).
- Even if you don't inline the method when writing IL, the JIT compiler may inline the method when it generates machine code anyway.

**UPDATE**

Okay, given your concrete example, let me explain the connection that I see to inlining.  If the method is called several times (e.g. calling `testmethod` twice in a row), then your approach won't work, because you'd need to branch back to different locations depending on which call was being simulated, but there's no simple way to do this (you can add a local variable to track the additional state and then use a conditional branch, but that's complex enough that it would probably undo any performance gains).  If it's only called once, then your transformation is basically equivalent to inlining, except with additional unconditional branches to and from the inlined method.  I think that it would make more sense to actually inline the method and get rid of the branches.  That is, given your example, it would look like this:

```
ldc.i4 5
// start of inlined call to testmethod
ldc.i4 10
add
ldc.i4 20
mul
// end of inlined call to testmethod
// other code from caller goes here
```

Then, my above comments about inlining apply.

Comment: Interesting, my understanding of method inlining was instead of making a call (or branch) the code was just basically pasted into where the call would be made. How would a label do that, as you still have the overhead of a jump/branch? Or am I off base with my definition of method inlining?

Comment: @Jetti - Well, I was extrapolating from your question a bit.  If you merely jump to the private method you want to call, how do you know where to return to once you're done?  You basically want to jump to the method and then presumably jump back to the caller, which seems to be the moral equivalent of inlining the method, except that it's not actually in line...

Comment: However, if there are multiple call sites, then you need to keep track of extra state to determine where to jump back to (or you need to inline the method multiple times).

Comment: It's certainly possible that I'm misunderstanding your proposed approach, in which case adding more clarifying details to your initial post would be helpful.

Comment: I'll edit my question to provide an example, hopefully it will shed some light on my thought process

Comment: @Jetti - thanks for the update.  I've added some extra thoughts to my answer.  Hope that helps.